# Program to print file contents unable to run, returns "Instruction at <address> referenced memory at <address>" error

Tags: c, file, command-line, memory-address, fault

I am learning the C language from a book.
I had reached the part of the book talking about files and command line arguments, but now I'm stuck at the part with this code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc,char **argv)
{
    FILE *f=fopen(argv[1],"r");
    int c;
    do
    {
        c=fgetc(f);
        printf("%c",c);
    }
    while(!feof(f));
}
```

When I run this (with the argument being the code's own file name for testing), an [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOnbV.png) appears:

> The instruction at 0x0000000000401474 referenced memory at 0x0000000000000006. The memory could not be read. Click on OK to terminate the program. Click on CANCEL to debug the program.

What is the meaning of this error, and how to fix it?

Comment: Always check `f` after calling `fopen`. Always check `argc >= 2` before accessing `argv[1]`. And note that *"the argument being the code's own file name"* would be `argv[0]` anyway.

Comment: and if the file is a binary file (not a text file) then `printf("%d ",c);` would be more useful.

Comment: I apologize for the misunderstanding, @WeatherVane, what I meant by "the code's own filename" is that the uncompiled C code was saved in a file called "tutorial.c", and I compiled the code and ran the executable with ```fileopen tutorial.c```

Comment: Can't reproduce, but the file I gave it as the argument *does exist in the default folder*. Check  `argc` and check `f`.

Comment: @WeatherVane apparently he uses Visual Studio, and the default folder of the executable is not the folder where the source file is.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments @Weather Vane, my code now works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the file pointer is not NULL so something like

```
if (f == NULL) {
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Also, files need to be closed when they are done being used.

```
fclose(f);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions @Ada Lovelace, I've implemented both and the code works now.